# Can't connect to SQL Server 1433 port for VM windows server externally on gcloud

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

Can't connect to SQL Server 1433  port for VM windows server externally on gcloud

I have already enabled the port in the firewall rules in gcloud, windows server and instance. I defined the port in the sql configuration manager.
The other ports like 8080, 23, 21 are working normally. Only port 1433 is not working.

Comment: What error do you get? Please, add more information about the error message.

Comment: We need more information so that we can better assist in regards to the issue you are facing.